# Where eclipse stores source exclusions

Tags: eclipse

I do source exclusion in my eclipse project in following way:

```
Right-click a project folder in Project Explorer tree and go to "Properties".
Resource -> Resource Filters.
Add as much exclusion filters for files/folders as you like.
```

But where Eclipse stores these stings?

Answer (score 1):

The filters are stored in the `.project` file for the project in the `filteredResources` entry.

For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>

    ... other things ...

    <filteredResources>
        <filter>
            <id>1453390382837</id>
            <name></name>
            <type>5</type>
            <matcher>
                <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter</id>
                <arguments>1.0-name-matches-false-false-xxx</arguments>
            </matcher>
        </filter>
    </filteredResources>
</projectDescription>
```

Note: You should not try to alter the `.project` file directly. The `IContainer` class has methods that plugins can use to alter the filters.

Comment: Strange, there is no <filteredResources> in my .project file

Comment: Have you set any filters? It only appears when filters have been added.